# Google Chrome cutting off jpeg when resized to a height taller than 65535px

Tags: css, google-chrome, jpeg

I have an image consisting of 187 frames from a video put on top of each other. Each frame is 320px wide and 180px tall resulting in an image 320px wide and 33660px tall. Link to image: http://reference.23.rekab.dk/7340/2758266/3f1faedac540f10a4bfe20ea579da3e7/video_frames/download/izotope-stutter-edit-frames.jpg

I wish to use this image to show one frame at a time, and to scale each frame to double width and height. To accomplish this, I have put the image inside a `div` measuring 640px times 360px with `overflow: hidden;`, and positioned the image absolutely to simply give it a negative `top` value depending on which frame I want to show (so to show the first frame, the `top` value is 0, and to show the fifth frame, the `top` value is set to -360 * (5 - 1) = -1440 pixels. Fiddle to show the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/kkabell/dJGp3/1/

This works fine until I reach frame number 183, giving the image a `top` value of -65520px: The resized image seems to be cut off at 65535 pixels by Chrome, hence not letting me show that frame in full -- and the rest of the frames not at all: http://jsfiddle.net/kkabell/tm6ZM/3/

I know the maximum height of a jpeg image is 65535 pixels (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpeg), but both Firefox and Safari is able to scale the image to a height taller than this.

- Is this expected behaviour in Chrome and is there any way around it?
- Is there a place where this "limitation" is documented?
- What behaviour should I expect in other browsers?

In my testing I have been using Google Chrome 25.0.1364.172 on OS X 10.8.2

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best option is to have the image at the original dimensions (not doubled), clip it in the original resolution, and then scaling the result 2x. Probably that could give you better performance also.

I guess that the internal implementation of the property will be a short, but I don't have any documentation about it.